# Numeros que terminan en 99 SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net

Hola buenos dias comunidad! Les queria hacer una consulta de como puedo obtener de una tabla(por ejemplo una columna precio) todos los numeros que terminen en "99" alguna idea? Gracias

Comment: Intentaste o probaste algo? la columna es numerica o de otro tipo?

Comment: se bienvenido, te recomiendo leer [ask] pues deberías mostrar lo que llevas o lo que has investigado al momento; para que de este modo la comunidad sepa desde que punto ayudarte; del mismo modo te invito a leer el [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo así

```
SELECT TABLA.PRECIOS AS PRECIOS
FROM TABLA 
WHERE TABLA.PRECIOS LIKE '%99'
```

Comment: Gracias por aportar!!! en general se espera que quien pregunto demuestre que intento o averiguo algo. Asi como esta, la pregunta es de baja calidad.